# d3 - Impossible to define new eventlistenters inside eventhandle function?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, event-handling, mouseevent

I'm working on a proof of concept that depicts some circles inside an svg element that move and change colour when i click on the svg element. That all works fine. I also wanted to add a mouseover event which changed the colour of the circle to red for example. That worked too.

However, when i updated the position/colour of the circles (those were random-generated values) the mouseover event had disappeared. I figured it was because d3 replaced the old circles with new ones and i didn't define my mouseover eventlistener in the update function, so i just copied it from the 'initialize' code. But then something weird happened. I got an '*Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function*' in the console, and the eventlistener didn't work. This is the code:

```
svg2.on("click", function(){
svg2["color"] = d3.rgb(Math.random()*256,Math.random()*256,Math.random()*256);

var circles = svg2.selectAll("circle");
console.log(circles);
circles.transition()
.duration(500)
.ease("circle")
.style("fill",svg2["color"])
.attr("cx",function(d,i){
  var val = (Math.random()<0.5)?-Math.random()*50:Math.random()*50;
  if(val+d[0]-d[2] >w2 || val+d[0]-d[2]<0) return d[0];
  else return d[0]+val;
})
.attr("cy",function(d,i){
  var val = (Math.random()<0.5)?-Math.random()*50:Math.random()*50;
  if(val+d[1]+d[2] > h2 || val+d[1]-d[2]< 0) return d[1];
  else return d[1]+val;
})
.attr("r",function(d){
return d[2];
})
///////// ERROR CAUSED BELOW //////////////
.on("mouseover",function(){
 d3.select(this).style("fill",svg2.color);   
 });
});
```

I did nothing wrong i thought, because i did exactly as i did before: i selected all my circles, set their attributes and defined an eventlistener with .on(), but it didn't work.

I was able to solve this by defining a function that does exactly as above and call it at the end of my 'update' code. This is the function:

```
function updateListeners(circles){
    circles.on("mouseover",function(){
         d3.select(this).style("fill","red");   
    })
    .on("mouseout",function(){
         d3.select(this).style("fill",svg2.color);   
    })
}
```

So it seems i can update eventlisteners of an object in a called function, but not in the callback function provided with the 'click' event?

Question: Why is that exactly? It's the exact same selection, but why does the 'hard' way work, and the 'easy' way doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the event listener after the `.transition()` in the first case. In the 'hard' case you are assigning the event listener to the selection without a transition. I don't think it works to transition into an event listener.

Try registering the event listener before the call to `.transition()` and see if that works for you.

Comment: To expand on that answer: transitions have `.on()` functions as well, but for different purposes and for different events. You were attaching the event listener to the transition, not the element.

Comment: Wow, you're both absolutely right! There was indeed a difference in my two code fragments, because upon loading the page i didn't use `.transition()`. The reason i put it so early in the chain is because most tutorials do it this way and i didn't think the order would be an issue, but now it's clear the order **does** matter for some functions. Thanks!